# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll

Tags: java, hibernate, scrollableresults

I have the following query,
When I tried to execute it using hibernate I get the following exception :

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>   using scroll.

In my code I have scroll has FORWARD_ONLY.
Can anyone please provide a perfect solution.

```
select * from (SELECT account_no    AS accountno,rownum r  FROM  sc_dcm_postpaid_index  WHERE  groupid = 'SBG-2012'  
and concat(trim(TO_CHAR(bill_date,'MONTH')),concat('-',TO_CHAR(bill_date,'YY')))='JUNE-12'  
AND ROWID  IN   (SELECT MAX(ROWID) AS row_no   ;   FROM sc_dcm_postpaid_index
WHERE groupid= 'SBG-2012'  and concat(trim(TO_CHAR(bill_date,'MONTH')),concat('-',TO_CHAR(bill_date,'YY')))='JUNE-12' 
GROUP BY account_no   HAVING COUNT (account_no) >= 1   ) ORDER BY account_no)where r >= 11  and  r <= 21..
```

Also when I change the query to

```
SELECT account_no    AS accountno,rownum r  FROM  sc_dcm_postpaid_index  WHERE  rownum >= 11  and  rownum <= 21 groupid = 'SBG-2012'  
and concat(trim(TO_CHAR(bill_date,'MONTH')),concat('-',TO_CHAR(bill_date,'YY')))='JUNE-12'  
AND ROWID  IN   (SELECT MAX(ROWID) AS row_no   ;   FROM sc_dcm_postpaid_index
WHERE groupid= 'SBG-2012'  and concat(trim(TO_CHAR(bill_date,'MONTH')),concat('-',TO_CHAR(bill_date,'YY')))='JUNE-12' 
GROUP BY account_no   HAVING COUNT (account_no) >= 1   ) ORDER BY account_no
```

And this is my Query:

```
SQLQuery mainQuery = (SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery(strReportQuery);
ScrollableResults itrDataList = mainQuery.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

Here `strReportQuery` is my query

It executes fine but it works only from rownum 1 to 10.
From next rownum it gives resultset as empty.

Thanks in Advance,
Bhargavi T.

Comment: How are you invoking your query?

Comment: SQLQuery mainQuery = (SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery(strReportQuery);
          

            ScrollableResults itrDataList = mainQuery.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);//Here strReportQuery is my query.

Comment: SQLQuery mainQuery = (SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery(strReportQuery); ScrollableResults itrDataList = mainQuery.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);//Here strReportQuery is my query.

Comment: I am having the same issue. (using a h2 database).